How to prove this non-increasing property of heat equation
Consider the heat equation system:
\begin{cases}
u_t = u_{xx} + f(x), & \\
u|_{x=0} = u|_{x=l} = 0, & \\
u|_{t=0} = 0, &
\end{cases}
where $f(x) \leq 0 $ for $ 0 \leq x \leq l $. The goal is to prove that $ u(x_0,t) $ is non-increasing with respect to $ t $.
To approach this, the equation system is transformed into:
\begin{cases}
v_t = v_{xx}, & \\
v|_{x=0} = v|_{x=l} = 0, & \\
v|_{t=0} = g, &
\end{cases}
where $g''(x) \geq 0$. The intuition is that a function which is convex upwards would not become convex downwards when $ v $ is governed by a heat equation system. Assistance is requested for this proof.

Do you mean $u \lvert_{\color{red}{x} = 0} = u \lvert_{x = l} = 0$? And is there a reason why you didn't just use an energy approach to prove $u$ is non-increasing?

An energy method isn't even needed here. Let $u_{h}$ be the solution of the above equation when $f\equiv 0$. Then, $u_h\equiv 0$. But, $\partial_t u\leq \partial_t u_h\leq 0$ , since $f\leq 0$. Thus $\partial_t u\leq 0$ and so $u$ is non increasing.

@MatthewCassell This is a mistake, I have already changed it, but I still don’t know how to do it.

@K.defaoite I cannot derive $\partial_tu \leq \partial_tu_h$ from $f \leq 0$. Could you provide more details?

@cutedunkey Sorry, I don't know what I was thinking. I must have been tired. Please disregard my comment.

To improve substantially on my last comment, I think you should be able to show
$$u(t,x)\leq u_{\max}(t,x)$$
Where $u_{\max}(t,x)$ is the solution of
$$\partial tu=\partial_x^2 u+f{\max}$$
With
$$f_{\max}=\max_{[0,l]}f\leq 0$$

It's easy to show $u_{\max}$ is decreasing since it can be written as
$$u_{\max}(t,x)=-\frac{4}{\pi}f_{\max}\frac{l^2}{\pi^2}\sin(\pi x/l)\left[\exp\left(-\frac{\pi^2}{l^2}t\right)-1\right]$$

@K.defaoite How can I get the magnitude relation between $\partial_t u_{max}$ and $\partial _t u$.
